# ASP MVC3 Returning json to ajaxform

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to do operations on returned json to ajaxform. I am not good in javascript enought to do it... I can Return Json from a method in controler, but Can i properly do things depends on  this json result?

I need to return status values, where status can be 1,2 or 2. In view I need to implement JS, which will add text to div, depending on json which this script get from a method. Everything should use ajax. Can anyone recommend me good tutorial ? Or simply write code for me which I will analyze.

Comment: [Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple extension method for jQuery:

```
jQuery.extend({
    postJSON: function (url, data, callback) {
        return jQuery.post(url, data, callback, "json");
    }
});
```

Then in your javascript block you do this:

```
$.postJSON('/controller/action',
{
    Param1: 1, 
    Param2: 2
}, 
function(data){
   alert(data.result);
});
```

And in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(int Param1, int Param2)
{
    return Json(new {
       result : "It Worked"
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Why bother with a `postJSON` wrapper?

Comment: Because I like it. You don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which changes the text inside a division based on the response from ur actionmethod...

```
//a class with properties.  

  Class Priveleges{
Public string StatusMessage{get;set;}
Public int StatusCode{get;set;}
 }


 //code inside controller
  [HttpGet]
  Public JsonResult Index{
  Priveleges obj=DecidePriveleges():
  Return Json(obj,allowget.true);
  }

 Private Priveleges DecidePriveleges(){
  Prilveleges obj;
   //prepare object based on server response
  If(response=="high"){
  obj=new Priveleges(){
  StatusMessage="high priveleges",
  StatusCode=1}
  }else if(response=="medium){
    obj=new Priveleges(){
   StatusMessage="medium priveleges",
   StatusCode=2}
 }else if(response=="low"){
   Obj=new Priveleges(){
   StatusMessage="low priveleges"‚
   StatusCode=3}
  }
  Return obj;



 //code inside ur view
//suppose you want to change the text inside 
//ur div when the page loads..
<div id="statusDiv"></div>

 //here is ur javascript.   
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('/controller/Index',function(data){
  $('#statusDiv').text(
   'You have '+data.StatusMessage);
  });
  });
  //here data,the parameter of getJson method.    
 //holds the data coming from our action
 //method...
```

Sorry for the code format..posted the code from my mobile...

hope this small examle may be helpful..